# Highlight an element in an active DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to highlight a `span(class="tiny")` element, when its div is active or clicked on any of its element...

I have already tried to highlight that element but no success....only was able to highlight the whole div....

```js
$('.main-class').on('click', '.row-fluid', function() {
    $(this).parent().find('.tiny').css('background-color', '');
    $(this).css('background-color', '#00fff0');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-class">
    <div class="panel-body" style="border: 1px solid black;margin: 5px;">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <a>
                <h1>One</h1>
            </a>
            <div class="col-md-1">
                <span>I am up</span><br>
                <span class="tiny">ID no -123395</span>

            </div>
            <div rel="tooltip" style="display: flex; justify-content: flex-end;">
                <div class="radio">
                    <label class="lead">
                        <input id="1" name="one" required="required" value="yes" type="radio">
                        Yes
                    </label>
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label class="lead">
                            <input id="1" name="one" required="required" value="No" type="radio">
                            No
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>


    <div class="panel-body" style="border: 1px solid black;margin: 5px;">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <a>
                <h1>Two</h1>
            </a>
            <div class="col-md-1">
                <span>I am up</span><br>
                <span class="tiny">ID no -123987</span>

            </div>
            <div rel="tooltip" style="display: flex; justify-content: flex-end;">
                <div class="radio">
                    <label class="lead">
                        <input id="1" name="one" tabindex="1" required="required" value="yes" type="radio">
                        Yes
                    </label>
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label class="lead">
                            <input id="1" name="one" tabindex="1" required="required" value="No" type="radio">
                            No
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Want to highlight Only the....`span class="tiny"`.. values when any of the element in `class="panel-body"` is activate.

Comment: *"STRICTLY USING JQUERY AND JS....as cannot add css file to it"* So use JavaScript to add a `style` element with the necessary rules.

Comment: Define "highlight."

Comment: hi T.J highlighting the elements text with a color

Comment: Yes, but **how**? A background color? A foreground color?

Comment: If I click a row in your example, it gets a cyan background. What is it doing / not doing that you want it not to do / to do?

Comment: Background color.......

Comment: I think you want '$(this).find('.tiny').css('background-color', '#00fff0');' to highlight just the .tiny span.

Comment: maybe you should change to $(this).parent().find('.tiny').css('background-color', '#00fff0');

Comment: @CarlosMartins thanks man.......solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $('.main-class').on('click', '.row-fluid', function() {
            $(this).parent().find('.tiny').css('background-color', '');
            $(this).parent().find('.tiny').css('background-color', '#00fff0');
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use CSS:

1. Add a class for highlighting
2. On click, remove that class from any element that has it and add it to the element for the click

Apparently (from the comments), although your code is calling `css` directly on `$(this)`, you want to find the `.tiny`, so I've updated to do that as well.

If for some reason you can't add CSS (an early version of your question said you couldn't), you can add the `style` element using JavaScript.

Example:

```js
$('.main-class').on('click', '.row-fluid', function() {
    $(".highlight").removeClass("highlight");
    $(this).parent().find(".tiny").addClass("highlight");
});
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: #00fff0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-class">
    <div class="panel-body" style="border: 1px solid black;margin: 5px;">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <a>
                <h1>One</h1>
            </a>
            <div class="col-md-1">
                <span>I am up</span><br>
                <span class="tiny">ID no -123395</span>

            </div>
            <div rel="tooltip" style="display: flex; justify-content: flex-end;">
                <div class="radio">
                    <label class="lead">
                        <input id="1" name="one" required="required" value="yes" type="radio">
                        Yes
                    </label>
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label class="lead">
                            <input id="1" name="one" required="required" value="No" type="radio">
                            No
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>


    <div class="panel-body" style="border: 1px solid black;margin: 5px;">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <a>
                <h1>Two</h1>
            </a>
            <div class="col-md-1">
                <span>I am up</span><br>
                <span class="tiny">ID no -123987</span>

            </div>
            <div rel="tooltip" style="display: flex; justify-content: flex-end;">
                <div class="radio">
                    <label class="lead">
                        <input id="1" name="one" tabindex="1" required="required" value="yes" type="radio">
                        Yes
                    </label>
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label class="lead">
                            <input id="1" name="one" tabindex="1" required="required" value="No" type="radio">
                            No
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Example adding the `style` element with code:

```js
$("<style>")
.text(".highlight { background-color: #00fff0; }")
.appendTo(document.head);
$('.main-class').on('click', '.row-fluid', function() {
    $(".highlight").removeClass("highlight");
    $(this).parent().find(".tiny").addClass("highlight");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-class">
    <div class="panel-body" style="border: 1px solid black;margin: 5px;">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <a>
                <h1>One</h1>
            </a>
            <div class="col-md-1">
                <span>I am up</span><br>
                <span class="tiny">ID no -123395</span>

            </div>
            <div rel="tooltip" style="display: flex; justify-content: flex-end;">
                <div class="radio">
                    <label class="lead">
                        <input id="1" name="one" required="required" value="yes" type="radio">
                        Yes
                    </label>
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label class="lead">
                            <input id="1" name="one" required="required" value="No" type="radio">
                            No
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>


    <div class="panel-body" style="border: 1px solid black;margin: 5px;">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <a>
                <h1>Two</h1>
            </a>
            <div class="col-md-1">
                <span>I am up</span><br>
                <span class="tiny">ID no -123987</span>

            </div>
            <div rel="tooltip" style="display: flex; justify-content: flex-end;">
                <div class="radio">
                    <label class="lead">
                        <input id="1" name="one" tabindex="1" required="required" value="yes" type="radio">
                        Yes
                    </label>
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label class="lead">
                            <input id="1" name="one" tabindex="1" required="required" value="No" type="radio">
                            No
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```